# Best practices for passwords on registration?

Tags: security, email, authentication, passwords, registration

I have a website which users register an account. On the registration field, the form fields are:

- Name
- Email
- Confirm email
- Username

But there is no password field. When they hit submit, they are emailed a password which is very complex, such as **LHJVjhwnv%uu5** or **RbWM9!jeDZUQb**.

I have appealed to my developer to instead make it so that the users can set their own password on the registration form. To confirm that password on the form, and then be sent a confirmation link to their specified email. Then this way they can at least log in to their account and verify their email via confirmation link. Or if they didn't, every time they log into the site it could remind them to verify their email etc or else they can't do much on the site (example). This way even if they **don't get** the confirmation link, they can **still** update their account email to a different email **and have it resent**. At least at this stage, they can log into their account, instead of **not at all**.

The response I have received from the developer is as follows

> "The problem with providing the password on registration is that
>   you'll have loads of fake accounts. So people that just register with
>   a non-existent email address. At least with the email validation
>   you're proving the user exists, to a certain extent. If they register with the wrong email, they can just re-register."

**I'd like to ask you all if the current approach the developer has employed is acceptable?**

**If not, what are some good reasons I could use to convince the developer to change?"**

I've tried to explain the following

- Every day there are 9-10 people who register **and then** directly use the "password reset" form **right after**. This form involves them putting in their email address that they signed up with, and then it emails them a link to SET a new password. So if they are setting a new password **anyway**, why not just have them set it in the first place on the registration form? Why would there be 9-10 people every single day using the password reset field, directly after registration? I'm pretty sure its because they are seemingly struggling with these complex passwords (which I am not against) that are being emailed to them and are missing a key or character, or do not seem to be aware of copy/paste or something like that. If they could just set their own password the **first time around**, they wouldn't need to run to the password reset field right after because of their emailed password not working. I thought it was weird how everyday theres always password reset emails. Not for everyone, but a good 9-10 people a day ever since I started using Mandrillapp to track the outgoing emails. This is backed up by the next point.
- Every day there are at least 2-3 people who fill out the contact form indicating that the password they received is not working. Could all be avoided if they just could set it on their own. There may be even more that just don't bother contacting.
- Out of nearly 8000 accounts, 50% have never logged in. My strong suspicion is that the Registration email containing their password goes to their junk folder/spam folder. This is despite me having proper SPF, DKIM, etc setup. 2 months ago, I decided to start using Mandrill to send mail to ensure it goes to the inbox, but still there's at least 1-2 people/day that say that they did **not** get their email.. which perplexes me. If they could define their own password, they wouldn't have to worry about waiting for their password via email, or not getting it entirely. This just further highlights my initial concern.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: There is also the common approach of choose your own password, but require validation link clicked before you can login

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have a working password-reset page in place, so you can use just the same code to do the registration:

1. Let the user register with his email.
2. Send a link with a token to the user, a hash of the token is stored in the database.
3. If the user clicks the link and if the token is valid, welcome him and let him enter his own password.

This is exactly what you already have for password resetting, your site becomes no more (un)secure because an attacker could as well use the password reset function.

Of course weak passwords are a problem, so rejecting weak passwords is a must. Again this is the same you would have to do on the password-reset page. For password-resets you wouldn't send plaintext passwords neither.

Unconfirmed accounts can be deleted after a certain period, it means the user didn't do anything with it. If necessary the user can register again. This only works if the user is not allowed to login before doing the confirmation, what supports the procedure above. Of course it depends on the website if this confirmation is that important though.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason not to send passwords in a mail is security: Mail isn't a secure medium. If you put a password in there, then many people can see it - consider allowing people to use your service *without* any kind of password instead to understand what I mean.

The main drawback of allowing people to chose their own password is that [95% will use `123456` or `password`](http://gizmodo.com/the-25-most-popular-passwords-of-2014-were-all-doomed-1680596951).

Most big sites use this approach to balance security, business needs and comfort:

- Allow user to set their own password. Reject the most simple ones (there are libraries for this). Note: Complex password rules drive customers away.
- Send a confirmation link via mail.
- Don't allow login until the link has been clicked.
- If they try to login anyway, tell them that they have to click the link first plus provide a "send confirmation link again" link in case the first mail was lost.

Answer (score -1):

> I have appealed to my developer to instead make it so that the users can set their own password on the registration form....

This opens you up to a plethora of weak password and reuse attacks. Reuse has been empirically studied and [reported between 50% and 76%](https://www.lightbluetouchpaper.org/2011/02/09/measuring-password-re-use-empirically/). Other academic studies have stated [nearly all users (almost 100%) reuse passwords](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/acp.1014/abstract).

So assigning passwords helps with major practical problems. After you assign the password, then you are subject to the same attack, though because a user may reuse the assigned password on another site.

---

> ...
>   I'd like to ask you all if the current approach the developer has employed is acceptable?

Yes, its acceptable as long as the password meets security requirements. I even prefer it, especially when user selected passwords are ***not*** checked against bad password lists.

Bad password lists are important because we know attackers use them. There are literally millions of passwords on them because of all the past breaches (did I mention password reuse is a pandemic problem?). The lists are easy to find, and one researcher recently released his list of 6,000,000+. See [How I Collect Passwords](https://xato.net/passwords/how-i-collect-passwords/#.VOReCUD2Q74).

---

Aaron is correct about email and plain text. You can actually place another security control to limit the exposure. Namely, require that your mail server use SSL/TLS or fail the connection.

Or, generate the password and display it to the user on the screen. Instruct the user to print the password so they don't forget it. I even tell my users to write them down and keep them in their wallet or purse.

The primary threat is a network based attacker attempting to gain unauthorized access to the server through weak/wounded/bad passwords. So an out-of-band/out-of-channel email is not too great a concern. And a lost wallet or purse is not too great a concern. The concern is the network based attacker guessing passwords or using {username,passwords} tuples from breaches of other sites.

---

> Every day there are 9-10 people who register and then directly use the "password reset" form right after. This form involves them putting in their email address that they signed up with, and then it emails them a link to SET a new password.

OK, that's a security defect since the user can circumvent the security control.

For what its worth, I regularly use a random password generator to generate passwords for accounts. I don't even bother writing them down. When I need to access the account, I simply go through the Lost Password process.

That's how low value these things are to me. Every damn site wants a user to manage an account and password. I'm tired of expending the energy to manage all the accounts, so I don't even waste the cycles on it.

---

> The problem with providing the password on registration is that you'll have loads of fake accounts. So people that just register with a non-existent email address. At least with the email validation you're proving the user exists, to a certain extent. If they register with the wrong email, they can just re-register

OK, so this is a different problem. BOT registrations are usually mitigated with a CAPTCHA. I've never really studied what to use for Real Users/Fake Accounts.

What is the benefit of a fake account? It seems to me the user is trying to get half pregnant. They either have an account, or they don't have an account.

---

> Out of nearly 8000 accounts, 50% have never logged in. My strong suspicion is that the Registration email containing their password goes to their junk folder/spam folder. This is despite me having proper SPF, DKIM, etc setup.

Well, that's a different problem (that you should confirm through testing). This speaks to displaying the password for the user and telling them print the page.

---

There's a lot more to the subject of password management. You should read Chapter 7 of Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).

---

> I have appealed to my developer...

Finally, you are the boss. Fire the developer or contractor if they are not following instructions or coding against requirements. I'd be damned before I begged someone who I was paying for services.

Programmers are a dime a dozen, and you can find plenty of them at places like [Rent-A-Coder](http://www.rent-acoder.com/). The Indians and Pakistanis work for next to nothing (under $10 USD per day in some cases). I don't know how they can work for so little and survive...